# Postbird - Connection Error

Tags: postgresql, docker

Eu criei um container no docker com o seguinte comando:

```
docker run --name database -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=senha -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

Quando eu tento acessar via Postbird, eu recebo o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que já tentei, mas não deu certo:

1. Setar o campo host para **localhost**. Erro: connect ECONNREFUSED.
2. Setar o campo host para o ip que o **docker é inicializado**. Erro: connect ECONNREFUSED.
3. Criar outro container **direcionado para a porta 5433**. Erro: connect ECONNREFUSED.

Alguém já passou por isso? Poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Galera, resolvi! :D

Caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema, a solução foi a seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu usei esse **ip** aí da img para conectar no Postbird.
E dei um restart no container com os comandos:

docker stop nome_do_container

docker start nome_do_container